# Keyboard app with number row on top

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

I need a keyboard application for my LG G Flex smartphone.

Those are the specs I need:

- Number row on top.
- Being able to change the word prediction dictionary without changing the layout.
- When long pressed on a letter, having the accented version of the letter, not a symbol like #.
- Option to disable auto formatting (especially auto space).

The ones I have tried: SwiftKey, ai.type, Kii, GO.

Which one would you suggest?

Comment: Hacker's Keyboard by Klaus Weidner?

Comment: Again, autospace when I hit a prediction

Comment: Hacker's keyboard was also my first guess (the most flexible I know of). While I'm not aware of any keyboard matching all your criteria: I've got an app-list for [Keyboards & Input Methods](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards) having them categorized, and linked reviews to each of them where available. Maybe that can provide a little help on your hunt?

Comment: most of the keyboards there are not in market anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try [Multiling O Keyboard + emoji](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kl.ime.oh&hl=en).

it supports different layouts, and you can make your own layout.

auto space is optional.