# Android keyboard with haptic feedback and discrete numbers

Tags: android, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I just installed a lolipop Cyanogenmod variant and it's got the AOSP keyboard.  I'm used to keyboards from HTC and Samsung and I have preferred them for various reasons.

I don't really like the AOSP keyboard and would like something like the Samsung keyboard.  I am looking for these features:

- Haptic feedback
- Discrete numbers above the keyboard
- English QWERTY

I do not like, and do not use, these features, and will turn them off if present :

- Sywpe
- Predictive text
- Autocorrect
- Spellcheck

I don't use emojis/smoticons that much, and I don't get why there are a million keyboards just for that.  As far as I can tell, keyboards come with an emoji/emoticon pane anyways.

I tried [Multiling O Keyboard + emoji](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kl.ime.oh&hl=en) based on this [similar but different question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11795/keyboard-app-with-number-row-on-top?rq=1) and it was lacking haptic feedback.  I couldn't figure out it's themes and options either.  I don't think it came with near as many options as the screenshots would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I like 'Hacker's Keyboard' [Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en), [github](https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard).

QWERTY
Number row
Vibration on keypress is configurable - you can even set vibrate duration.

You can even play with things like key height in the settings.